# Is it right that Enthalpy can only be used to calculate Q for isobaric processes?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, first-law-of-thermodynamics

I made a little derivation for the Enthalpydifference $\Delta H$. I got as a solution:

$\Delta U+\underbrace{\Delta p\cdot V_{1}+p_{2}\cdot\Delta V}_{a}$

Now I do want to compute the transferred heat of the process by using the 1st law of thermodynamics:

$Q=\Delta U+\Delta E_{kin}+\Delta E_{pot}+W_{rest}+W_{vol}$

Where I divided Work $W$ in to $W_{rest}$ and $W_{vol}=\int_{1}^{2}p\left(V\right)\cdot dV$

So for the case that $\Delta V=0$ I can easily calculate $Q$ with the a table for $U$, if I know $\Delta E_{kin}$, $\Delta E_{pot}$ and $W_{rest}$:

$Q=\Delta U+\Delta E_{kin}+\Delta E_{pot}+W_{rest}$

because $W_{vol}=0$

It is similar for the case $\Delta p=0$:

Although $W_{vol}=p \cdot \Delta V \neq 0$, $a$ does simplify to $a=p \cdot \Delta V$ and therefore I can write $\Delta H = \Delta U + W_{vol}$

$Q=\Delta H+\Delta E_{kin}+\Delta E_{pot}+W_{rest}$.

But what about all the other cases? Am I right that there is no simple way to calculate $Q$ by using $\Delta H$?

Comment: No there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Denbigh, "The enthalpy change of a closed system is thus equal to the heat absorbed under *two* restrictive conditions, namely, that there is constancy of the pressure and that the only form of work is due to the volume change of the system.  In a galvanic cell, where electrical work is done, the heat absorbed is not equal to the change in enthalpy."